# Primefaces dataTable find component using wigetVar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Now I'm using Primefaces 5.1.In my dataTable set to focus paginator. To find specify dataTable to setFirst.But I want to know **dataTable widgetVar** do same process?

**stud.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable value="#{stud.nameList} var="std" widgetVar="mainDataTable">
......
</p:dataTable>
```

**stud.java**

```
public void setPageDataTable() {
    final DataTable d = (DataTable) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
        .findComponent("form:templateTable");
    int first = 1;
    if (d.getRowCount() % ROWS_DATATABLE == 0) {
        first = (d.getRowCount() - ROWS_DATATABLE);
    }
    else 
    {
        first = (d.getRowCount()/ROWS_DATATABLE)*ROWS_DATATABLE;
    }
    d.setFirst(first);
}
```

Comment: why via widgetVar? Why not just via id?

Comment: I want know find component only via Id or widgetVar also find component ?

Comment: Search StackOverflow, the internet and more...

Comment: Please check this http://blog.hatemalimam.com/intro-to-primefaces-widgetvar/